# How to install a Python wheel under an alternative package name? (in my specific case, PyCryptodome under the "Cryptodome" package name)

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

The installation information page of [PyCryptodome](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html) says the following under the ["Windows (pre-compiled)" section](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-pre-compiled):

> 1. Install PyCryptodome as a wheel:
>
> > pip install pycryptodomex
>
> 2. To make sure everything works fine, run the test suite:
>
> > python -m Cryptodome.SelfTest

There are several problems with this though:

1. Contrary to what these instructions say, this will *not* install PyCryptoDome as a wheel, but it will rather download it and try to build it, resulting in an error if you don't have the correct build environment installed for the C components included in this package (and the entire mess related to this is the biggest benefit of using a wheel instead to begin with).
2. Even if I instead download the correct wheel file from [PyCryptoDome's PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodome), I must (as far as I know?) instead use a command-line as follows to install it:

> > pip install c:\some\path\name-of-wheel-file.whl

This in turn makes it install under the default "Crypto" package instead of the "Cryptodome" package explicitly mentioned in the instructions (and therefore colliding in a breaking fashion with any pre-existing installations of the PyCrypto package).

**So, my question is:**

**Is there any way to install a wheel file under a different package name than the default one?**

PyCryptodome does not seem to provide any specific wheel files for installing under this alternative package name, so if this is impossible, I have a big problem (because I already have PyCrypto installed). :-(

*PS.
Some more context regarding the need for the alternative package name can be provided by the following quote from the same [installation page](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html) that is linked above:*

> PyCryptodome can be used as:
>
> 1.
>   a drop-in replacement for the old PyCrypto library. You install it with:
>
> > pip install pycryptodome
>
> In this case, all modules are installed under the Crypto package. You can test everything is right with:
>
> > python -m Crypto.SelfTest
>
> One must avoid having both PyCrypto and PyCryptodome installed at the same time, as they will interfere with each other.
>
> This option is therefore recommended only when you are sure that the whole application is deployed in a virtualenv.
>
> 2.
>   a library independent of the old PyCrypto. You install it with:
>
> > pip install pycryptodomex
>
> You can test everything is right with:
>
> > python -m Cryptodome.SelfTest
>
> In this case, all modules are installed under the Cryptodome package. PyCrypto and PyCryptodome can coexist.

So, again, all I want is to install it as described under alternative 2 in this quote, from a wheel file, but the problem is that the provided wheel files seem to only default to the package name described under alternative 1 in this quote (i.e. "Crypto").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. The only way to achieve this by recompiling the wheel yourself after you modified its name in the `setup.py`.

Comment: Thanks (although of course not the answer I was hoping for). And for the record, the pip install command from the PyCryptodome documentation above was found to work with the most recent version of pip, but not with the version included with Python 3.4 (which rather went with the source version instead for some strange reason, any guesses why?). More info in this bug ticket: https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/16 Also, the wheel files for the alternative package name were made available on a completely separate page at PyPi, here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodomex